# Turkish Airline & Aegean Airline Interline Baggage

Tags: transit, luggage, turkish-airlines, aegean-airlines

I'm planning to book the flight route of HKG/IST/ATH/HER in 2 legs. With the first leg being HKG/IST/ATH with Turkish Airline and the second leg being ATH/HER with Aegean Airline. And I have to buy a separate ticket for the 2 different legs.

However, the layover time in ATH is only 1hr15min and it will be a transit from international to domestic and 1hr15 is not going to cut it with 2 separate tickets if I need to clear customs and re-check the bags.

As Turkish and Aegean are both members of Star Alliance, does anyone know whether I can interline and tag my bags from HKG when I check-in and only collect my bags when I land in HER? If so, do I need to check-in online for the ATH/HER leg and print the boarding pass before I check-in in HKG or is it possible for me to collect the boarding pass at the transfer counter in ATH? Is it possible on 2 separate tickets with 2 different airlines?

If none of the above work, I will have to wait in ATH for close to 6 hours for the next flight to HER.. If anyone has experience in interlining / tagging bags between Turkish and Aegean Airline in an international Dometic transit?

Comment: Why do you have to book the trip as separate tickets? If the airlines are allied, surely they will have interline agreements that lets one of them to issue tickets for a combined itinerary.

Comment: ITA Matrix does find a connection like the one your describe (HKG-TK71-IST-TK1845-ATH-A37306-HER) with 1h15 layover in Athens, which can be issued as a single booking. It may not be so from the airlines' own websites, but if you go to a travel agent, they should be able to issue it.

Comment: (It's even a single fare HKG-HER published by Turkish specifically for interlined itineraries with Aegean).

Answer (score 1):

If you have booked two, completely separate tickets, you can ask at check in to have them 'tagged to the final destination.' If both of your tickets are on one reservation, with one Passenger Name Record, that makes it easier and you shouldn't have a problem checking bags through.

If completely separate, with your first leg on an airline such as Turkish, it should not be difficult, but you need to request this. You may want to arrive early at your departure airport, since the check-in agent at needs to be able to print baggage tags that conform to the interline agreement and  get your bags to your final destination.

Aegean has [online check-in](https://en.aegeanair.com/travel-information/check-in/online-check-in/) from 48 hours up to 30 minutes before flights, via computer, tablet or smartphone from aegeanair.com or Aegean apps on [Google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aegean.android&hl=en) and [Apple](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/aegean-airlines/id470826821?mt=8) stores.